# Hadoop 2 node Cluster Communication Query

Tags: hadoop, cloud, cluster-computing

I have a 2 node Hadoop Cluster (Master and Slave). Both the nodes are up and running as I can check their health on the localhost:50070.

So I get this 150 mb folder (with plain text) into the Master's HDFS. Then   I run the next command:

```
  hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /In/ /Out/
```

The issue is that I only get the same execution time as when running the command with one single node. To me it seems like the nodes are not really doing any parallelism!!

I am checking the logs on the slave and I have the following:

```
2015-03-18 23:52:49,455 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1680309327-31.220.211.10-1426721698684:blk_1073741856_1032 src: /31.220.211.10:46035 dest: /31.220.211.35:50010
2015-03-18 23:52:51,191 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /31.220.211.10:46035, dest: /31.220.211.35:50010, bytes: 3796560, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_688133940_1, offset: 0, srvID: fbea19bb-06ee-4868-af5c-0cb9699064f3, blockid: BP-1680309327-31.220.211.10-1426721698684:blk_1073741856_1032, duration: 1734807025
2015-03-18 23:52:51,191 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1680309327-31.220.211.10-1426721698684:blk_1073741856_1032, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-03-18 23:52:59,733 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-1680309327-31.220.211.10-1426721698684:blk_1073741856_1032
```

And on the Master:

```
15/03/18 23:52:50 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1934686363_0001_r_000000_0' done.
15/03/18 23:52:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1934686363_0001_r_000000_0
15/03/18 23:52:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
15/03/18 23:52:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/03/18 23:52:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1934686363_0001 completed successfully
15/03/18 23:52:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 38
```

Is this normal? Why I am being said that both my nodes are alive but when running the wordcount example it does not parallelize? But instead it acts like everything runs local!!

I can't seem to find an answer to this problem, so I would be very happy if I could get some help.

Comment: I have managed to make it working. I will be posting what was the actual problem, probably some other hadoop 2.6.0 user will be getting into this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that even though both my nodes where recognised as alive the job was still running locally.

That was because the yarn file was missing this property:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>master</value>
</property>
```

I have also triple checked that all the config files are the same on all the nodes!! After everything was checked carefully, the job ran globally.

Another thing would be to take attention when configuring the cluster as Hadoop 1.x and Hadoop 2.x don't share the same configuration parameters.